# How to show categories in product creating page in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have this form in the Laravel admin backend which adds new products to database.

`productCreate.blade.php`

```
 {{ Form::open(['files' => true]) }}
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title" class="control-block">Product title:</label>
    {{ Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title" class="control-block">Product description:</label>
    {{ Form::textarea('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    <span class="help-block">HTML is allowed.</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title" class="control-block">Product price:</label>
    {{ Form::text('price', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title" class="control-block">Assign Product to Category:</label>
    <select class="form-control">
        <option value="one">Category 1</option>
        <option value="two">Category 2</option>
        <option value="three">Category 3</option>
        <option value="four">Category 4</option>
        <option value="five">Category 5</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title" class="control-block">Product image:</label>
    {{ Form::file('image', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</div>

<hr />

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create new product</button>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

My question is how to show this select/options values from database. I want to be able to assign products to categories. Where I should make query and how to add them here in the view?

In admincontroller i have functions for product creation which load the view

```
public function productsCreate() {
    return View::make('site.admin.products_create');
}
```

and I tried to make it like this

```
public function productsCreate() {
    $categories = Categories::paginate(15);
        return View::make('site.admin.products_create', [
            'categories' => $categories
        ]);
    //return View::make('site.admin.products_create');
}
```

but then I got message

```
production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Cannot redeclare AdminController::productsCreate() ...
```

So how exactly I can query database table categories and show categories in the form?

May be because I already have categories selection in admin controller?

```
public function categories() {
    $categories = Categories::all();
    return View::make('site.admin.categories', [
        'categories' => $categories
    ]);
}

public function productsCreate() {
//      $categories = Categories::paginate(15); 

        return View::make('site.admin.products_create', [
            'categories' => $categories
        ]);
    //return View::make('site.admin.products_create');
}
```

Comment: do you mean, assigning categories to products ?

Comment: I mean I want to show categories to this form. This form is for adding products. How to show categories in this form?

Comment: Look at my response below, but paginate the categories ? i suggest you to show all the categories

Comment: How to take all of them?

Comment: i edited my response, to take all of theme use get() method : $categories = Categories::get();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the categories in the`productsCreate` function, and you must remove the old `productsCreate` function, you declared it twice :

```
public function productsCreate() {
    $categories = Categories::get();
    return View::make('site.admin.products_create', [
        'categories' => $categories
    ]);
}
```

For the html :

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="title" class="control-block">Assign Product to Category:</label>
<select class="form-control">
    @foreach($categories as $categorie)
    <option value="{{ $categorie->id }}">{{ $categorie->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

I hope that will help you.

Comment: are you sure that your **categories** table is not empty ?

Comment: It's not it was my mistake because here `{{ $categorie->id }}">{{ $categorie->name }}` should be `{{ $categorie->category_id }}">{{ $categorie->category_name }}`.

Comment: ah okey, it was just an example :)

Comment: yeah sure , you create a foreign key on **category_id** on your product table, and don't forget to name your select `<select class="form-control" name="category">`

Comment: I've made it like this and works perfectly! Thank's again!